# convert json_decode format into json_encode format

Tags: java, php, json

I am getting this JSON response form my web server. as i searched that this format is json decode format. how i will convert this into json encode format.

```
stdClass Object
(

[id] => 4ffc88e7-1413-fa9c-423c-53fc701b1044

[entry_list] => stdClass Object

    (
        [first_name] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => first_name
                [value] => dharmendra
            )

        [last_name] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => last_name
                [value] => singh
            )

        [primary_address_city] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => primary_address_city
                [value] => gwalior
            )

        [primary_address_street] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => primary_address_street
                [value] => chinchwad
            )

        [primary_address_state] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => primary_address_state
                [value] => mp
            )

        [phone_mobile] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => phone_mobile
                [value] => 55555555
            )

        [primary_address_country] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => primary_address_country
                [value] => in
            )

        [primary_address_postalcode] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => primary_address_postalcode
                [value] => 4444444
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: how will i convert it into json format

Comment: duh!, [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), is this a trick question?

Comment: yes bro, do u know about that

Comment: That's not JSON.  It looks like the output of `print_r` or similar..

Comment: no i am getting this response from my web server

Comment: php convert the json into this using JSON_decode method

Comment: your getting a response thru a `print_r()`? oh my goodness

Comment: Are you getting that actual text back from the web server?  If you paste the URL into your browser, you get that?  Or is that filtered through whatever function call you used to call the web server from your PHP code?

Comment: is it convertible in to json again

Comment: Right. So, the web server sends JSON.  Then `json_decode` turns it into an object so that your PHP code can work with it.  You want to go back to JSON?  Just call `json_encode` on it. (On the object, not on the result of `print_r`'ing the object.)

Comment: no i am getting this through an API so i can not make modification in side it

Comment: After you call the API, take the object you got back from the API call - in your code - and call json_encode on it.  Why is this hard?

Comment: no mark i done that it giving me NULL in the place of json code

Comment: done that also returing null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is json response which came from the SugerCRM RESTapi

the solution is write **print(json_encode(set_result))** in the place of

**print(set_result)**